# Restructure a query in Impala/Hive that is using subquery to create new column in table

Tags: sql, subquery, impala

I am converting SQL query to Impala. The SQL query is using a subquery in select to create a new column and is as follows-

```
select *, (select min(day)
           from date_series 
           where day > t.work_day) as next_work_day
from table1 t
```

However, Impala does not support subquery in select for creating new column and this query fails. Can I please get help to rewrite this query in a way Impala can execute.

Purpose of Query: Find the next working day for the work_day column.

Table1 is the outer table and contains

`table1 contains 4 columns including the work day column`

`date_series contains all working dates stating from 2019-06-18 to current_day + 5` like

```
   2019-06-20
   2019-06-21
   2019-06-24
   .
   .
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
select t.*, ds.next_day
from table1 t left join
     (select ds.*, lead(day) over (order by day) as next_day
      from date_series ds
     ) ds
     on t.current_work_day >= ds.day and
        (t.current_work_day < ds.next_day or ds.next_day is null);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, 
Thanks for the reply and for suggesting this. The lead function in my impala is giving the one value ' 2019-06-20' in the lead column and also the corresponding day column. 

` Day ---              --- Lead(day)
 2019-06-20           2019-06-20
2019-06-20           2019-06-20
`

Comment: @ShriyaGupta . . . That could only occur if there are duplicates in `date_series`.

Comment: This was really helpful. it worked and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your query as following

```
select 
    t.*,
    work_day 
from table1 t 
join (
    select 
        min(day) as work_day 
    from date_series
) ds
on t.current_work_day = ds.work_day

where ds.work_day > t.current_work_day
```

Comment: Hi Zealous, 
THe above code will produce only one result for the right table which is minimum value in date_series. What I am trying is to get the a day next in series to work_day column which is in outer table. 
So for every value in work_day column I want the next day in the dates series table.